# How to test custom template tags in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-testing

I'm adding a set of template tags to a Django application and I'm not sure how to test them.  I've used them in my templates and they seem to be working but I was looking for something more formal.  The  main logic is done in the models/model managers and has been tested.  The tags simply retrieve data and store it in a context variable such as

```
{% views_for_object widget as views %}
"""
Retrieves the number of views and stores them in a context variable.
"""
# or
{% most_viewed_for_model main.model_name as viewed_models %}
"""
Retrieves the ViewTrackers for the most viewed instances of the given model.
"""
```

So my question is do you typically test your template tags and if you do how do you do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a short passage of one of my test files, where self.render_template a simple helper method in the TestCase is:

```
    rendered = self.render_template(
        '{% load templatequery %}'
        '{% displayquery django_templatequery.KeyValue all() with "list.html" %}'
    )
    self.assertEqual(rendered,"foo=0\nbar=50\nspam=100\negg=200\n")

    self.assertRaises(
        template.TemplateSyntaxError,
        self.render_template,
        '{% load templatequery %}'
        '{% displayquery django_templatequery.KeyValue all() notwith "list.html" %}'
    )
```

It is very basic and uses blackbox testing. It just takes a string as template source, renders it and checks if the output equals the expected string.

The `render_template` method is quite simplistic:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def render_template(self, string, context=None):
        context = context or {}
        context = Context(context)
        return Template(string).render(context)
```

Comment: How do you test this outside of a project scope, say, for a reusable app? Rendering a template string that include `{% load custom_tag %}` does not seem to work, at least without additional work?

Comment: Answered my own question: use `register = template.Library(); template.libraries['django.templatetags.mytest'] = register; register.tag(name='custom_tag', compile_function=custom_tag)`.

Comment: what is `self` in your code sample? `My TestCase` object does not have `render_template` method

Comment: @Gregor Müllegger could you please update your answer and include the `render_template` method? thanks

Comment: @yamm: I just added a snippet containing the `render_template` method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

You guys got me on the right track.  It's possible to check that the context was correctly changed after the render:

```
class TemplateTagsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):        
    def setUp(self):    
        self.obj = TestObject.objects.create(title='Obj a')

    def testViewsForOjbect(self):
        ViewTracker.add_view_for(self.obj)
        t = Template('{% load my_tags %}{% views_for_object obj as views %}')
        c = Context({"obj": self.obj})
        t.render(c)
        self.assertEqual(c['views'], 1)
```

Answer (score 11):

A good example of how to test template tags [test of flatpage templatetags](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/flatpages_tests/test_templatetags.py)

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be rendered as templates, so you could write a test that includes a simple 'template' using your templatetag as a string and just make sure it renders correctly given a certain context.

Comment: These tags only render an empty string and instead change the context but I should be able to test for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I was testing my template tags, I would have the tag, itself, return a string containing the text or dict I was working with ... sort of along the lines of the other suggestion.

Since tags can modify the context and/or return a string to be rendered -- I found it was fastest just to view the rendered string.

Instead of:

```
return ''
```

Have it:

```
return str(my_data_that_I_am_testing)
```

Until you are happy.